# Python: Combining two lists to make a new list

Tags: python, list

I would like to combine two lists in Python to make one list in the following way:

Input:

```
list1 = [a, b, c, d]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Result should be:

```
list3 = [a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1 ... ]
```

Comment: Not entirely clear. If all these are lists of strings, then you forgot all the quotes.

Comment: Is the content of the list a bunch of strings? e.g. `list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` `list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']` `list3 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1'...]`

Comment: Sorry, they are all strings.

Answer (score 4):

Or using list comprehension as a one liner, instead of nested loops:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list3 = [x + str(y) for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

Note: I assume you forgot the quotes in `list1`, and `list3` is supposed to be a list of strings.

Comment: Or should it require more nesting or nested for's confuse you, then `itertools.product(list1, list2)` instead

Comment: @JonClements What would be the best way to join the elements of each tuple created by `iterools.product` the way he/she wants in `list3`?

Comment: Same as you are is fine... `x + str(y) for x, y in itertools.product(list1, list2)` or you could do `'{}{}'.format(*items) for items in product(list1, list2)` or whatever else you can think of

Comment: I suppose to be most flexible, `[''.join(map(str, items)) for items in product(list1, list2, list3)]` etc...

Comment: @JonClements Got it. This may be handy when dealing with stuff involving combinatorics. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
list3 = []
for letter in list1:
    for number in list2:
        newElement = letter+str(number)
        list3.append(newElement)
print list3
```

returns this:
`['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']`